# Cassandra column family limitation

Tags: cassandra

I am wondering is there any columnfamily count limitations in keyspace?
And Is there any rows limitation in columnfamily?

Which schema is better?
To create columnfamilies
CF1_customer1, CF2_customer1,
CF1_customer2, CF2_customer2,
or to have CF1 and CF2
with
custmer_id as primary_key?

Answer (score 0):

There are overheads per column family so you will find schema operations slow with more than a few hundred CFs.  The only (practical) limit to the number of rows is your cluster size.  People routinely use Cassandra with many billions of rows.

For your example, it is much better to have CF1 and CF2 with customer_id as the row key.  This will be more efficient and scale better, because the data is partitioned according to the row key so different customers will be stored on different nodes.